# How to Create Separate index created for separate input types

Tags: logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I have Below `logstash-syslog.conf` file where it has two different input types one as `type => "syslog"` and another is `type => "APIC"` . So, i need two separate output index created as `syslog-2018.08.25` and `APIC-2018.08.05` .

I want these index to be created Dynamically, i tried  something `index => "%{[type]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"` but it did not worked and killed the logstash.

Could you please suggest what's wrong i'm doing in the below config which needs to be fixed for both config and Index type.

Below is the configuration logstash file:

logstash Version is : 6.2

```
$ vi logstash-syslog.conf
input {
  file {
    path => [ "/scratch/rsyslog/*/messages.log" ]
    type => "syslog"
  }
  file {
    path => [ "/scratch/rsyslog/Aug/messages.log" ]
    type => "APIC"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp } %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
  if [type] == "APIC" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{CISCOTIMESTAMP} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
   }
 }
}
output {
              elasticsearch {
                hosts => "noida-elk:9200"
                index => "syslog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                #index => "%{[type]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                document_type => "messages"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed for me as its working for me.

```
 $ cat logstash-syslog.conf
    input {
      file {
        path => [ "/scratch/rsyslog/*/messages.log" ]
        type => "syslog"
      }
      file {
        path => [ "/scratch/rsyslog/Aug/messages.log" ]
        type => "apic_logs"
      }
    }

    filter {
      if [type] == "syslog" {
        grok {
          match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp } %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
          add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
          remove_field => ["@version", "host", "message", "_type", "_index", "_score", "path"]
        }
        syslog_pri { }
        date {
          match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
     }
    }
      if [type] == "apic_logs" {
        grok {
          match => { "message" => "%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{CISCOTIMESTAMP} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} (?<prog>[\w._/%-]+) %{SYSLOG5424SD:f1}%{SYSLOG5424SD:f2}%{SYSLOG5424SD:f3}%{SYSLOG5424SD:f4}%{SYSLOG5424SD:f5} %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
          add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
          remove_field => ["@version", "host", "message", "_type", "_index", "_score", "path"]
       }
     }
    }
    output {
            if [type] == "syslog" {
            elasticsearch {
                    hosts => "noida-elk:9200"
                    manage_template => false
                    index => "syslog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                    document_type => "messages"
      }
     }
    }

    output {
            if [type] == "apic_logs" {
            elasticsearch {
                    hosts => "noida-elk:9200"
                    manage_template => false
                    index => "apic_logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                    document_type => "messages"
      }
     }
    }
```